# How to automatically close a browser tab after it opens when I run a GET request in a Google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, get

I'm calling a Google Apps Script webapp with a GET request by clicking a link to the webapp's Url, to initiate a function.

The browser automatically opens a tab with the return response.

How can I automatically close that tab immediately or after a few seconds of displaying a message.

I looked around and saw alot of suggestions to add a `<script>` tag, But it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

**Code.gs**

```
    function doGet(e) {
var pram = e.parameter.param;
    
// Run some code based off of the parameter

        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('confirmation'); 
    }
```

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
function start(){
    setTimeout(function(){ window.top.close(); }, 3000);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="start()">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Your function is being Initiated<br>Please Wait...</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should work. Check browser console logs in devtools

Comment: @TheMaster I checked the console. I'm not so good at reading what it says, but I did find this message `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.` Does that shed any light light? and what's the solution if it is the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Well then, I guess [it is no longer possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is this cannot be done. please see @TheMaster's comment.